# Build a two-level resource using react-admin

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

If I have an API endpoint called `apps` which will retrieve a list a different apps.

And I also have an API endpoint called `apps/{app_id}/app-versions` which will retrieve a list of release versions that is under a specific app from above.

Both above will show a list.
The first one shows only brief data, ex:

```
[
  {
    id: 'app1',
    latest_version: '1.0.1'
  }
]
```

The second one shows detail data, ex:

```
[
  {
    id: 'release2',
    version: '1.0.1',
    change_log: 'something'
  },
  {
    id: 'release1',
    version: '1.0.0',
    change_log: 'something'
  }
]
```

I want to have a page that shows out lists from first API, when click one of them, show the detail data from second API.

Now I have a `<Resource name="apps" list={AppList} />` which list out all the apps.

And I want to use `<Resource name="apps/:id/app-versions" list={AppVersionList} />` to list out all the versions of a specific app.

What is the best practice to achieve it through `react-admin`? 
Thanks!